# (msvc# express) publish c# project to include a file (e.g. .MDB, .XML)

Tags: c#, publish

My app needs to open an Access mdb file and an xml file (which are stored in bin\Release) to read and write data.  The question is, if I am to publish it, how should I include them so that the setup file will install them into the same folder that the exe will run from (Local Settings\Apps\2.0(...))?

I already tried adding them to the project but then they ended up in the next folder to the one containing the exe.

Alternatively:
If I can't with vc# express, is there another way to do this (through a 3rd party software maybe)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wix.sourceforge.net/

WiX - Windows Installer XML is an OS tool you can use to build an installer you can tell it where to put each file and create folders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Standard Edition and up also include a built-in designer for creating installation files that can do what you're asking for.  If you want to stick with Express, WiX is probably the better choice, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try using InnoSetup. Its great for Access application installers .